# Pig Gunt Shell Doesn't return any result and hangs

Tags: apache-pig

Installed in cygwin/windows 7

pig 0.11/embedded hadoop.

**Problem**: Grunt shell is prompted. Any keyboard inputs and  gives *NOTHING*.
System appears to be doing *NOTHING*. You enter PIG command and the cursor simply jumps down and stays there. Any help will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Wuhu..ClassPath issues. Simple yet very complicated. Windows classpath always baffles me. Thanks for the edit. 
Solved.

Dev7

Comment: I have same problem, can you write more descriptive answer about what was the issue and how you fixed it so that it can help others as well.

Comment: Can you share your classpath ? It might be useful for me and others to understand what might be missing from out part ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Couldn't look at the question. Here is what I did. Previously, I had given the path to pig directory where the old jar resides which has problems with win7. But after I build new jars, my path was pointing to the old build directory where it wrote the jar files. I changed that to the latest built jar files. Yup! silly path problems. What happens is, when you execute, pig gives the >Grunt prompt. But when you give a statement then here is where it messes with the path. Hopefully this helps. Thanks.